# How to explain os.path.abspath(__file__ + "/..")?

Tags: python

As title

```
import os

print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(os.path.abspath(__file__ + "/.."))
```

Output:

```
/Users/myname/my_proj/__init__.py
/Users/myname/my_proj
```

I want to know _*file*_+"/.." meaning exactly.

Comment: What would qualify as "better"? Using pathlib? Don't use `+` on strings?

Comment: I want to know __file__+"/.." meaning exactly. Because it looks more concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know *file*+"/.." meaning exactly.

[meaning](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/num/dotdot.htm)

> A ".." can also be used in a command line or in a file path to go back
> one directory. For example, when using either the MS-DOS cd command or
> Linux and Unix cd command typing cd .. goes back one directory.

In other words

- `/home/user/../` (or `/home/user/..`) same as `/home`
- `/home/user/../anotheruser` same as `/home/anotheruser`
- `/home/user/./` (or `/home/user/.`) same as `/home/user`
- `/home/user/./anotheruser` same as `/home/user/anotheruser`

However, that is interesting question. This hack don't work for Linux commands:

```
ls -l /var/log/system.log
-rw-r-----@ 1 root  root  165030 Jan 27 13:18 /var/log/system.log

ls -l /var/log/system.log/..
ls: /var/log/system.log/..: Not a directory
```

But! python `abspath` library ignores is the last element of path folder or directory

Comment: Ha ha ! That's why I am rarely use it in python :))

Comment: Yep. I was surprised about this behaviour. `..` usually used only with folders: `folder_name/..`. `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` is more correct.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`os.path.dirname()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)

```
print(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Comment: Or the newer `print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent)`